# Form inputs not showing the same across browsers

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MSv5h/2/) that shows a user registration form. I am using Twitter Bootstrap. I have just realized that it shows fine when using Firefox.

However, when using Chrome or IE, the textfields are slightly above the input-group-addons where I have glyphicons.

How can I make the form inputs show correctly across browsers?

```
<div class="input-group">                                               
     <span class="input-group-addon glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span>
     <?php
          echo $this->Form->input('username', array('class' => 'form-control',
               'placeholder' => 'Username', 'required' => 'required', 'type' => 'text'));
     ?> 
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Move the glyph class out and into their own spans.

```
<span class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span></span>
```

Always try to keep elements separate from their containers to prevent styles from conflicting with each other.

Comment: I follow this rule because I know I have to, but have always been confused by it. Since it all cascades anyways, why does it make a difference? Doesn't it just apply the last attribute it encounters?

Comment: @ShawnTaylor yes but in this case, the .glyphicon has attributes that were affecting the dimensions of the .input-group-class